# Publish Service refrence when wsdl file is stored in my derive

Tags: c#, wsdl, service-reference

I have a wsdl File. I put it in a folder in derive E. I add a service refrence in my solution and I put a code in my config file like this

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="IpgWebServiceExporterServiceSoapBinding2">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="IpgWebServiceExporterServiceSoapBinding3" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IpgWebServiceExporterServiceSoapBinding2"
        contract="webserviceref.IPGService" name="IPGServicePort1" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior" />
  </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
        ....
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

in my local system It is working good. but when i publish it on server and use IIS It is not working. 
Is it nessesary I copy wsdl file in a derive on server?

Comment: What error are you getting when calling the service published in IIS?

Comment: when I put this code in web config on server i get blue line below  contract="webserviceref.IPGService" and when I run code I get exception  when I want  create a new from  a class.  and I shoud say I don't copy wsdl file in a server. Is this necessary?

Comment: it's not necessary for WSDL to be in the server

Comment: When i pubsh code what dll/ file i should copy for web service? Only i change web config and project.dll in bin?

Comment: @Coder1409 what dll/file i shoud put in server? I only publish code and change webconfig and project.dll un bin.